# java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class cannot be instantiated at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

Tags: android

I am trying to add a custom dialog with a rating bar and a few more widgets to my small project but stuck on this error. kind of a beginner so I'll be glad if u can make it simple for me, thanks

I've tried to change the class to an abstract java class.

```
  package com.a.shon.scoutszone2;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RatingBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public  class ZoneActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {

    Button btnPeula;
    ImageView ivMap;
    ImageView ivZone; //Will Change in the future
    //ListView lstZone;
    Zone current = new Zone();
    private Drawable[] maps;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //add a dialog/menu to logout and manager activities
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zone);

        btnPeula = findViewById(R.id.btnPeula);
        ivMap = findViewById(R.id.ivMap);
        maps = new Drawable[4];
        maps[0] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map, null);
        ivMap.setImageDrawable(maps[0]);
        ivZone=findViewById(R.id.ivZone);//Will Change in the future
        maps[1] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tzone, null);//Will Change in the future
        ivZone.setImageDrawable(maps[1]); //Will Change in the future

        //lstZone = findViewById(R.id.lstZone);
        //lstZone.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        // lstZone.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<Zone>(this, android.R.layout))
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.the_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item)
    {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.itemManager:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Manager...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent manager = new Intent(this, manager.class);
                startActivity(manager);
                break;
            case R.id.itemLogout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Logging out...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.itemRating: //make it a dialog not an activity!
                Toast.makeText(this, "Start Rating!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                showCustomDialog();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onPeula(View v)
    {
        Intent peula = new Intent(this, PeulotActivity.class);
        startActivity(peula);
    }

    private void showCustomDialog()
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        final RatingBar mRatingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.mRatingbar);
        final TextView tvRatingscale = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRatingScale);
        final EditText etFeedback = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFeedback);
        Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        mRatingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
                tvRatingscale.setText(String.valueOf(v));
                switch ((int) ratingBar.getRating()) {
                    case 1:
                        tvRatingscale.setText("Very bad");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tvRatingscale.setText("Need some improvement");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tvRatingscale.setText("Good");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        tvRatingscale.setText("Great");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        tvRatingscale.setText("Awesome. I love it");
                        break;
                    default:
                        tvRatingscale.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // if (etFeedback.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                //     Toast.makeText(ZoneActivity.this, "Please fill in feedback text box", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // } else {
                etFeedback.setText("");
                mRatingbar.setRating(0);
                //Toast.makeText(ZoneActivity.this, "Thank you for sharing your feedback", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I expect that when the dialog will be opened the application won't crash, but actually every time the button of opening the dialog is clicked, the app crashes
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class cannot be instantiated at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Builder to construct your dialog instead of instantiating it directly.

[Documentation on Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs)

> The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid
>   instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following
>   subclasses:
>
> AlertDialog A dialog that can show a title, up to three buttons, a
>   list of selectable items, or a **custom layout**.

Code Sample:

```java
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
    // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // sign in the user ...
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
               }
           });
```

Also, if you'd like to properly handle lifecycle events, consider using a `DialogFragment` and instantiate your dialog in that fragment.